# Bring back a workflow task to previous state in Alfresco activiti workflow

Tags: alfresco, activiti

I would like to bring back a workflow task to previous state in Alfresco activiti workflow.
For example, there are two reviewer A and B. The workflow is serial, A is the first reviewer and B is the second. After A accepted the task, the task is assigned to B. At that time, A would like to bring back the task from B. What api method should I use to implement this behavior? (it's not possible?)

Comment: What do you mean with "bring back"?

Answer (score 1):

What you mean is Reassigning a task to another user, which is in your case the same user who did the first step.

You can to this by the following: http://forums.activiti.org/content/reassign-task-another-user

Take a look in the Share web components for task-edit-header.js. There is a reassign button in share which does a bit you're asking for. Check which calls alfresco makes a reuse that.

Comment: Hi, I did not mean reassigning a task to another but placing a task back to previous state. After "A" bring back the task from "B" and "A" accepted again the task, "B" takes it again (according to the flow). Is it possible?

Comment: No it's not possible in Activiti workflow. You can't step 'back' after you've selected Next. You can only go forward, meaning one can build in a lot of if's after each step so it's looping until it goes 2 steps further.

Answer (score 0):

why not putting an exclusiveGateway after B that evaluates a boolean, so depending to its value ,workflow will either complete or return to A